# An adjective to describe someone who has a “good personality”?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I can't think of a word to describe someone with a good personality and who you can't think of a bad word to say about them.

> Samuel is such a ______ guy. You never hear a bad word said against him.

Answer (score 1):

***[Good-natured](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good-natured)*** may suggest the idea:

> - having an easygoing, cheerful disposition.

or ***[affable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affable):***

> - showing warmth and friendliness; kindly; mild; benign

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I think **nice** will work:

> friendly, kind, or polite.

He's such a **nice guy**. I like Clare – **she’s really nice**.

(Longman)

Depending on the context, you can also try:

1. **lovely** -- very nice, kind, and friendly.

> All the people I met on the course were lovely.

2. **pleasant** -- friendly, polite, and easy to talk to (used especially about someone that you do not know very well)

> I only met her once or twice but she seemed pleasant.

3. **sweet** -- very kind and gentle

> Kylie’s a very caring, sweet person.

4. **charming** -- behaving in a polite and friendly way, which makes people like you and want to do things for you

> A charming hostess

5. **good-natured** -- having a nice kind character and not getting angry easily

> Everyone likes Mike because he’s always so good-natured.

6. **great** -- used about someone who you like and admire a lot (informal)

> He’s a great guy!

(Longman)

Answer (score 0):

**Debonair**?

> : c. 1200, "mild, gentle, kind courteous," from Old French debonaire,
>   from de bon' aire "of good race," originally used of hawks, hence,
>   "thoroughbred" (opposite of French demalaire). Used in Middle English
>   to mean "docile, courteous," it became obsolete and was revived with
>   an altered sense of "pleasant, affable" (1680s). [Online Etymology
>   Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=debonair)
>
> *Someone debonair is charming or suave. They have good manners, and
>   they probably look good too*.
>
> *This French word has a fancy feel to it, and it is a fancy kind of word. Being debonair is a specific form of being charming that applies
>   mostly to men. When you're debonair, you impress women, other men, and
>   pretty much everyone with your manners, wit, and style. Debonair a
>   little bit of an old-fashioned word. Old movie stars like Cary Grant
>   were often called debonair, but not many people are today.*
>   [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/debonair)